# Configuring Jetty Acceptor Threads

Tags: jetty, embedded-jetty

Is possible to configure the number of acceptor threads in jetty? Is the number of accpetor threads twice the number of cores in the machine by default? According to the documentation acceptor thread goes to a blocked state when it is waiting requests. Does having many acceptors threads without requests(In blocked state) a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocked Acceptor threads are normal operation.

Since you are using `embedded-jetty`, just use the `ServerConnector.setAcceptors(int)` to set the number of acceptors you want.

If you are using the `jetty-distribution`, then set the start property appropriate to what you want ...

`jetty.http.acceptors` an int indicating the number of non-ssl http acceptors (-1 for auto-configuration based on hardware/os settings)

`jetty.ssl.acceptors` an int same as above, but for ssl/https connectors.

> Note: The default behavior for Acceptor count is the best configuration. You would want to configure a different (lower number then default) if you have more then 4 connectors, or are running some crazy custom virtualization (ignore this for well behaved virtualization such as docker, virtualbox, or vmware)